# Colorize options from a select form

Tags: jquery

I have a select form filled with following data:

```
<select id="attachments[32][color][]" name="attachments[32][color][]"> 
    <option value="">-- Select a color --</option>
    <option value="AliceBlue">AliceBlue</option>
    <option value="Amethyst">Amethyst</option>
    <option value="AntiqueWhite">AntiqueWhite</option>
    <option value="Aquamarine">Aquamarine</option>

</select>
```

Theres a way to colorize options backgrounds from select with their own value?

Im using colors from:
http://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names

More at:
http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/select-single/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please stop writing tags in your question titles.

Comment: I don't think Amethyst is a recognized color btw http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colornames.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/mbBX8/

```
$('option').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color',$(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome or Firefox on a Mac. Seems to work in Ubuntu though.

Comment: @Felix: Works on Chrome on Windows 7. Do options even support the background-color property on Chrome/Mac? If not, I think he's hooped. Have to find another way to style it.

Comment: Not sure but it definitely seems to be a Mac OS "problem".

Comment: Well I don't have a Mac to test. You can experiment if you want, that's the best I can do :)